# Boxing vs ValueType by reference; What's the difference?

Tags: .net, memory, boxing

There were a couple recent questions about boxing a ValueType as an Object, in particular whether it happened in certain instances.

Something I realized I don't know is, what is the difference between "boxing" a ValueType (treating it as a referenced Object) and simply accessing it by reference, for instance using ref or out keywords (where what you are passing is just a "pointer")? In both cases, the value is somewhere where you can point to it (for an Object it's the heap, for a locally-scoped ValueType it's... where, exactly?).

If I had to guess, from what I know of C++, I would say it works like this: a ValueType accessed by reference (let's say via parameter keyword) remains on the level of the call stack for which it is scoped, but a "shortcut" pointer to that variable's bucket in the stack is created and becomes part of the next layer of the stack. Because the value is already stored in memory (probably even the CPU cache), you don't have to instantiate something new on the heap; the only new thing is the pointer, which is its own ValueType (an IntPtr) and is itself stored on the stack, so AFAIK it would be faster than putting something in the heap.

Is this what's going on, or is there something else afoot?

EDIT: More clarity:

```
public void TakesAnObject(Object obj) {...}

public void TakesAnIntValueType(ref int myValue) {...}

public void AnotherIntParameterMethod(out int myValue) {...}

...

//this locally-scoped variable is simply created on the stack.
int myInt = 5;    

//Performs boxing; an Object is instantiated in the heap that holds the 
//variable value from the stack, and that is passed by ref.
TakesAnObject(myInt);

//Apparently does NOT perform boxing, but we're still dealing with a reference.
//So what's going on?
TakesAnIntValueType(myInt);

//Again created on the stack, with the default 0.
int anotherInt;

//Again, apparently no boxing, but we're dealing with a reference to anotherInt.
AnotherIntParameterMethod(anotherInt);
```

Comment: It would help if you could give complete examples of the two scenarios you're talking about. It's very unclear what you mean at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class references may be freely copied, and are allowed to exist indefinitely.  One can think of them as identifiers for objects which are stored (always) as stand-alone items on the heap.  To avoid overusing the term "reference", I like to think of them as ObjectIDs.

When a routine accepts a parameter by reference, that reference is a special type of thing which is outside the normal class system (I'll call it a ParameterReference).  Unlike an ObjectID, which can exist indefinitely, a ParameterReference is only allowed to exist for the duration of the called function.  Further, unlike an ObjectID which always holds a reference to a standalone object, a ParameterReference holds a reference to either a local variable on the stack, a field within a class Object, an item within an array, or a field within a struct which itself matches one of these descriptions.  If the ParameterReference points to a local variable, that variable will cease to exist once it goes out of scope; attempting to use the ParameterReference after that time could cause data corruption.  Since the scope of the variable is guaranteed to extend at least until the called routine exits, however, and since the ParameterReference will cease to exist at that time, there's no danger of a ParameterReference accessing a variable that no longer exists.

Comment: Nice answer. Pretty much the same as Tedd's, but far more detail. I'll let other votes decide which of you get the uptick, but a thumb to both of ya

Comment: KeithS: Thanks.  As I've noted, I think the term "reference" is confusing, so hopefully using "ObjectID" makes things clearer.  BTW, I wish .net allowed one to do more with "real" references, like have a value-type property return one.  Many of the complaints Eric Lippert et al. seem to have about mutable structs are really complaints about the difficulty of having properly-functioning references to them.

Answer (score 1):

`TakesAnObject(myInt);`
has to box because it is received as an object type (reference type). If the target was a value type it would had been copied instead.

`TakesAnIntValueType(ref myInt);`
 is a reference to the same memory area as myInt, so if changed "both change". If it was not ref the value would had been copied instead.

Comment: This is kind of what I thought; there's still a reference, but in the case of a valuetype passed by reference instead of being boxed, the reference is to the existing variable in the stack. When being boxed, a new object is instantiated in the heap, the value copied, and then copied back from the heap to the stack when the function exits. The savings is in the object creation and copy process; making a pointer is cheap.

Answer (score -1):

You're close. When the value type is boxed, it is copied to an object structure which lives on the GC heap. The object structure has the usual preamble for objects, and the bits which come after this are the blitted value type structure. When it is unboxed, this structure is recopied onto the stack.

Comment: What if the value is unboxed into an instance field in a class? What if the value is being unboxed into a variable captured in an iterator or an anonymous delegate? etc.

Comment: @Jason - go ahead and answer for yourself, then, if you want to cover every case. However, this answer is targeted not to the general case, but the case that I understand the questioner is driving at. Sometimes less is more.

Comment: For the scope of the question I was asking (local variabl;e being boxed vs referenced), the answer is correct. However, it's not complete. I already knew that boxing did to a value type, what I wanted to know is how passing a valuetype by reference differed from boxing/unboxing.

Comment: @codekaizen: Your answer is wrong. It is not necessarily the case that an unboxed value type is copied onto the stack.

Comment: @Jason: Looking at ECMA-335, section 12.1.6, the Virtual Execution System, I find the following - Unboxed: as a "value type instance" that does not carry type information at runtime and that is never 
allocated directly on the heap.  It can be part of a larger structure on the heap – a field of a class, 
a field of a boxed value type, or an element of an array.  _Or it can be in the local variables_ or 
incoming arguments array (see §12.3.2). [emph. mine] Given the current implementation of the CLR, this is the stack. While incomplete, my answer stands as correct.

Comment: That's a disjunction which means the clause "it can be in the local variables" can be false while the rest of the statement is true (as in the case when the value is unboxed into a field of a class, or a variable captured in an iterator, etc.). You make the absolute statement "when it is unboxed, [it] is copied onto the stack." This is false. Unboxed value types are copied onto the stack except when they are not. I already stated as much when I said "[i]t is not necessarily the case that an unboxed value type is copied onto the stack."

Comment: @Jason: 'You make the absolute statement "when it is unboxed, [it] is copied onto the stack."': the error here appears to be yours, since you assume this is an absolute statement, when I provide no such qualification. While it may be an error on my part for not carefully specifying where it is and is not so, it is, after all, an answer to a question about where the value goes from the heap to the stack, and normal conversation affords assuming this context. I took advantage of this, perhaps too much. However, my answer is not wrong.

Comment: There is a tremendous amount of confusion around the whole "value types are allocated on the stack" nonsense. Your answer did nothing to not add to this confusion and it fact adds to it because it _clearly_ reads like "boxed value types are unboxed onto the stack" and doesn't have any qualifiers that this isn't the whole story. When unqualified, this statement is false, and therefore your answer is wrong.

Comment: Just because the OP's question contained confusion on the issue doesn't mean you had to allow that confusion to persist. The OP starts by asking about locally-scoped value types. Even those don't have to be on the stack.

Comment: @Jason, I'm sorry you were so confused when reading my post. Apparently the OP understood it, which was my aim. If you will continue to assign a qualifier to my statement when it wasn't - especially after this lengthy discussion wherein I clarified it - my intended meaning, well, I guess that's your viewpoint. It is, however, a well established understanding that natural languages make poor specifications, and insisting that everything be spelled out doesn't make a point wrong; just your particular interpretation.

Comment: I can't stress this enough: not all local variables live on the stack, and not all unboxed value types are unboxed onto the stack. This has nothing to do with interpretation or anything else. You made a statement, it wasn't qualified and therefore the normal rules of English lend the reader to interpret it as an unqualified absolute statement. It is not me that is adding or needs to add qualifications. That is on you, dear writer.